# Liquibase not creating diff changelog based on JPA Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

I tried to find the answer in already asked questions as well as in this post that some users recommended: http://www.operatornew.com/2012/11/automatic-db-migration-for-java-web.html but without any luck.

The problem is that I have a complete configuration of Liquibase for my Java project with Maven build tool and Postgres DB but even though I have defined Hibernate entities, the Liquibase **diff** does not take them into consideration and **does not produce changelock based on JPA annotated entities.**

I tried everything but with empty *changelock-master.xml* and with defined 2 entities the resulting *diff.xml* is empty.

Here is my *pom.xml*:

```xml
        <!--LIQUIBASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Here I have my *liquibase.properties* defined:

```
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.victus.applied.entity?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
referenceUsername=testusername
referencePassword=
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/applied
username=testusername
password=
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-diff.xml
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
```

In my *application.properties* I have also:

```
##Liquibase
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
logging.level.liquibase = INFO

##Postgres DB
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/applied
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=wiktordyngosz
spring.datasource.password=

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.messages.basename=validation
```

I defined simple two entities, for example one of them:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

When I have an empty *changelock-master.xml* file and invoke **mvn liquibase:diff** to generate changelock based on my entities the resulting changelock is empty.
The log looks like this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: src/main/resources/liquibase.properties
[INFO]   'outputChangeLogFile' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/applied
INFO 20.02.19 21:19: liquibase-hibernate: Reading hibernate configuration hibernate:spring:com.victus.applied.entity?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO 20.02.19 21:19: liquibase-hibernate: Found package com.victus.applied.entity
INFO 20.02.19 21:19: liquibase-hibernate: Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO 20.02.19 21:19: liquibase-hibernate: Found hibernate.enhanced_idfalse
lut 20, 2019 9:19:26 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
lut 20, 2019 9:19:26 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
lut 20, 2019 9:19:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
lut 20, 2019 9:19:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
lut 20, 2019 9:19:27 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
lut 20, 2019 9:19:27 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO 20.02.19 21:19: liquibase-hibernate: Using dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
[INFO] Performing Diff on database wiktordyngosz @ jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/applied (Default Schema: public)
INFO 20.02.19 21:19: liquibase: src/main/resources/liquibase-diff.xml exists, appending
[INFO] Differences written to Change Log File, src/main/resources/liquibase-diff.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: Can't help much with the actual question, but for future searchability, Liquibase refers to the file containing all your migrations as a changelog, not a changelock.

Comment: @UOMan Judging by `liquibase.properties` you trying to generate changelog by comparing schema in db (postgres) and your actual jpa entities. Are you sure that schema in db is empty? Because, if there is already schema defined in postgres, it's logical that generated diff is empty.

Comment: In such cases you should set the liquibase plugin into verbose mode to gain more information: `<configuration><verbose>true</verbose></configuration>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause could be that the Liquibase plugin doesn't find your compiled classes on the classpath.

I find it suspicious that you refer to your logfiles by `src/main/resources/...`. When executing the Liquibase plugin as part of the Maven build, all resources should be available on class path directly, e.g. `changelog-master.xml` (without the relative path).

Try executing the `diff` goal as part of the Maven build after compiling.
This POM configuration binds the plugin to the [process-classes phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference):

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
    <dependencies>
...
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>diff</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

To execute this, run `mvn process-classes` or a later phase like `mvn test`.